# Kendo TreeView: check if a node has siblings or children

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have got a Kendo TreeView:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .BindTo((IEnumerable<TreeViewItemModel>)ViewBag.MyTree)
    .Events(e => e.Select("test"))
)
```

Here's the Javascript function fired when selecting a node:

```
function test(e) {
    var id = $(e.node).data("id");
    var description = this.text(e.node);
    //if (.....) {
    //   ..... something here 
    //}
    alert('Id: ' + id + '\nDescription: ' + description);
}
```

The above shows an alert with the Id and Text of the node. Now, I want to check if the selected node has siblings or children and do something if it does, and some other thing if it doesn't.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for siblings with `e.node.parentNode.childNodes.length - 1` and for children with `e.node.childNodes.length - 1`

Comment: Thank you, that works. I just had to tweak that into `e.node.parentNode.childNodes.length - 1` for siblings and `e.node.childNodes.length - 1` for children. Please correct your code so I can accept it as answered